# View logic or not for Drop Down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC application. I have following class:

```
public class Organization {
    // Organization ID
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // Organization name
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // City where organization is located
    public string CityName {get;set;}
}
```

This class is using in Model:

```
public class OrganizationsModel {
    public Organization[] Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

In a view I want to render drop down list for picking an organization:

```
@Html.DropDownList("org", Model.OrganizationsList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id, Text = String.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Name, x.CityName) }))
```

I have some fear about this:

```
new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id, Text = String.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Name, x.CityName) }
```

Is the view is wrong place for combining text for each option in drop down list? Maybe I should place this code to view model or controller? Looks like current code breaking MVC paradigm.

Comment: as per my opinion it's fine. you can at least use this in view. Ideally you should not use any data manipulation kind of logic in view.

Answer (score 3):

The code you're performing in the view is only related to creating display elements, so the view seems the right place to do that. You don't want to create `SelectListItem`, a class only related to display, in your model or controller.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view thats perfectly okay. The view is tailored to the gui needs. If you can push the concatenated information into the view without creating a model fields, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just place a property with only a getter:

```
public string GetCombinedName {
    get {
        return String.Format("{0} ({1})", this.Name, this.CityName);
    }
}
```

On the `Organization` model. Or split it out on a `OrganizationViewModel` with this property on.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree that this is completely fine in the view, but what I would say is that you should ensure that if this logic is required in **multiple views**, you shouldn't repeat the logic in another view, you should push it up into shared logic, such as in your business layer, or into a Html helper.